# Organizing (splitting?) controller while maintaining URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have a large web application that is a mix of WebForms and MVC.  The URLs we work with look as such www.something.com/Secure/Module/SomeAction.  When we used to work with Webforms Module was a folder, as we had as many ASPXs as we needed under that folder.  With MVC we're taking a similar approach, where Module translates to a controller, containing all the action.  The problem that we're running into is that if the Module has something like 20 - 30 actions it's getting really messy.  For example if we have a PersonReport, that usually translates to several actions dedicated to serving that report alone (to facilitate ajax calls etc).  Our actions are fairly thin, they populate the model (usually calling WCF services) and that's about it.  Nevertheless it can easily creep up to 1500 lines of codes, and we start utilizing regions to organize sections of the controller.  Creating a new controller (by default) will obviously stray away from our URL pattern.  Any suggestions on how to better organize this mess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute routing if you plan to use MVC 5. This will allow you to specify custom routes for each Action method with attribute

The previous versions allow you to override the default routes through RouteConfig.cs file. Example would be

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: “ProductPage”,
    url: “{productId}/{productTitle}”,
    defaults: new { controller = “Products”, action = “Show” },
    constraints: new { productId = “\\d+” }
);
```

See this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) for more info. 
Hope this helps.